# Portas lógicas no SQL

Tags: sql, lógica

Existe algum comando que represente a porta lógica **XNOR** ou **NOR** no SQL? Algo que por exemplo negue a saída do XOR

Comment: Qual tecnologia de banco de dados estas a utilizar?

Comment: Mais importante: na sua concepção, quais os valores de `NULL XOR NULL`, `NULL XOR TRUE`, `NULL XOR FALSE`?

Comment: Estou usando o Access mesmo, porém tentando fazer uma consulta dentro no modo SQL.

Answer (score 5):

**SQL ANSI '92**

```
Operação                Modelo
XOR                     (a != b)
XNOR                    (a == b)
bitwise XOR             (a OR b) AND NOT (a AND b)
bitwise XNOR            NOT ((a OR b) AND NOT (a AND b))
```

XOR (ou OU exclusivo) é o operador de diferença; XNOR, o de equalidade. Assim, operações diretas podem ser simplificadas.

**Microsoft (Transact-SQL), Oracle (PL-SQL)**

```
Operação    Operador    Modelo
XOR         ^           @a ^ @b
XNOR        ^ ^1        @a ^ @b ^ 1
```

Os dois SGDBs compartilham o mesmo símbolo para o operador lógico XOR (`^`).

Fonte:

[^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR) (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx)

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou bastante...no access o de equivalencia é o eqv.

Answer (score 3):

Tu pode criar a função. Se for duas variáveis (A e B) é só tu obedecer a lei `A XOR B = (A' E B) OU (A E B')`, onde `'` simboliza a negação.
Para fazer o XNOR é só negar o XOR ou usar `A XNOR B = (A' OU B) E (A OU B')`

No SQL ficaria

```
A XOR B = (((NOT A) AND B) OR (A AND (NOT B))
```

e

```
A XNOR B = ((A OR (NOT B)) AND ((NOT A) AND B))
```